# How to invoke a controller method from Koa router

Tags: typescript, routes, middleware, koa

I'm trying to invoke a method from the `koa-router` but I get the following error;

> [ts]
>   Argument of type (req: Request, res: Response) => Promise is not assignable to parameter of type `'Middleware<ParameterizedContext<any`, IRouterParamContext..

I've tried with yield as well well but not invoking my controller method.

Below is my router code;

```
import * as Router from 'koa-router';
import * as controller from "../controllers/index";
const router = new Router();
router.get("/", controller.index);
export {router};
```

In the controller, I'm trying to render the `index.ejs` in a method as illustrated below;

```
export let index = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.ctx.render("./index", {page: "Home", menuId: "home"});
};
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late to the game, but I had a hard time finding the solution so here it is:

You just need to use koa's `ParameterizedContext` instead of the default one.

```
import * as Koa from "koa";
import Router from "koa-router";

const router = new Router();

router.get("/", (ctx: Koa.ParameterizedContext) => {
    return ctx.render('index');
});
```